# How to cite a number of a journal's volume?

Tags: biblatex, journal-publishing

I would like to cite a (French) paper in a journal. According to this journal, the correct citation should be something like :

```
Author, «Title», Journal's name 2015/1 (n° 167), p. 67 à 88.
```

`2015/1` means that this is the first issue of this journal in 2015. This issue is the n°167. Therefore, the issue `2015/2` will be the n°168.

I am wondering how to cite correctly this paper with `biblatex`. The biblatex manual is not very clean about using `volume` or `number` for `167`. The most logical thing to do seems to use `number` for `167` and `volume` for `2`.

> number field (literal) : The number of a journal or the volume/number of
>   a book in a series.
>
> volume field (literal) : The volume of a multi-volume book or a periodical

```
 @article{test,
   author =   {Author},
   title =    {Title},
   journaltitle = {Journal},
   year =     2000,
   number = 167,
   volume = 2,
   pages = {67--88}}
```

However, the result is not correct. It seems there are two volume of the 167 issue:

[image]

The `2` applies to the year and should be displayed next to it. *How do I do this correctly with biblatex?*

MWE:

```
 \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{test,
   author =   {Author},
   title =    {Title},
   journaltitle = {Journal},
   year =     2015,
   number = 2,
   volume = 167,
   pages = {67--88}}
 \end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose,
     hyperref,
     backend=biber,
     date=year]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution, if I've well understood what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper, french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{test,
   author = {Author},
   title = {Title},
   journaltitle = {Journal},
   year = 2015,
   issue = 2,
   volume = 167,
   pages = {67--88}}
 \end{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose,
     hyperref,
     backend=biber,
     date=year]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\def\bibrangedash{ à~}}
%
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
 \usebibmacro{journal}%
 \setunit*{\addspace}%
 \iffieldundef{series}
 {}
 {\newunit
 \printfield{series}%
 \setunit{\addspace}}%
 \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
 \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
 \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
 \usebibmacro{issue}%
 \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
      \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\usebibmacro{date}%
       \setunit*{\addslash}
      \printfield{issue}%%
}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Thank you. It works well with verbose style. However, if I change the bibliography style (let's say, for example, for authoryear-comp), it doesn't work anymore (I obtained `Journal/2`). So my document couldn't be change to another style.

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised biblatex doesn't provide a way to handle this "style". It's quite common in French Journal to use "Year/issue number" syntax.

Comment: For `authoryear-comp`, add the loading time option `mergedate=false` (it's an option that is specific to authoryear styles).

Comment: I didn't understand it was only for a specific entry…

Comment: My mistake: my post should say "it's working for one entry but it creates issues for a large bilbiography". Indeed, if I choose a authoryear style, I would have twice the year in every entry just in order to handle correctly one.

Comment: But the only solution is to create a biblatex style which suits to this Journal style. If anyone knows such style....

Answer (score 3):

A difficult question. Looking a bit around in citation manuals and description one find

> *Volume number*: a continous number which is expected to rise with every issue/edition of a journal. So a monthly journal will have
>   volume number 120 after 10 years.
>
> *Issue number*: A number for one specific article in one issue, the fourth article is "issue 4". Needed to identify an article if the
>   journal doesn't have continuous pagination.

Looking at the **descriptions** in biblatex.pdf all the fields *issue*, *number*, *volume*, *month* seems to relate to the journal edition and not to the single article in the journal.

Looking at your (and other) **output** I would say that *volume*=*volume number*, *number*=*issue number* (and so article related), and *issue* and *month* can be used to refine the year.

I'm not quite sure if I really did understand your description of the numbering system of your journal but it sounds as if you should use `volume={167}` and either `issue={1}` or `month={1}`.  Then you should try out existing biblatex styles to check if they give an suitable output or define your own style.

Comment: `month={1}` is an horrible trick that I would not recommend. `month` is here to give the month the publication was made (on top of its year), and it can be printer, depending on the style, as "January" for instace. So using that fields to give the issue doesn’t sound like a good idea.

Comment: I didn't mean it as a "trick" only as a suggestion. I don't know what the number refers too. (I get quite a number of monthly journals.)